# Test if numbers are divisible by 4, up to 100 digits

Tags: c++

Simply enough, I practice programming via an online judge. This is a rather stupid problem, really easy. However, The judge keeps saying I have a wrong answer. I'm just going to paste the code which is just a few lines, and a link  to the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int cases = 0;
    string solution = "";
    cin >> cases;

    if (cases > 100)
        return(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
        int temp = 0;
        cin >> temp;
        if ((temp % 4) == 0)
            solution +="Y";
        else
            solution +="N";
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < cases; j++) {
        if (solution[j] == 'Y')
            cout << "YES";
        else
            cout << "NO";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

The problem is simply to output YES or NO for each number that is input that is divisible by 4, YES for if it is, NO if its not. The problem and every minute detail can be found: http://coj.uci.cu/24h/problem.xhtml?abb=1306

This is rather silly, but I'm going bonkers here trying to figure out what I'm doing WRONG!

Comment: The question says the numbers will have at most 100 digits. A number that large will not fit into an integer.

Comment: The problem is this `solution[j]`.  `solution` has already been declared as a string, not an array.  Edit: please disregard.

Comment: Whoops. I actually just added that after my first initial attempts that were unsuccessful. Other than that..any other glaring mistake?

Comment: `std::string` overloads the `[]` operator, doesn't it?

Comment: @EdManet He's looping through the chars of the string, so no, thats not the problem

Comment: @user2228517 An `int` won't fit a 100 digit number.

Comment: You're making the matter more complicated than it needs to be by using a string for storing results. Allocate an array of bools of the provided size instead

Comment: Your problem is indeed integer rollover. Think about powers of 10 which are divisible by 4…

Comment: Have you read the question at all? The input could have up to 100 digits, you can't just read that into an int!

Comment: Also why are you storing the results before writing? cin and cout shouldn't interfere, so you could do all this in one loop with no storage.

Comment: @Dave I believe it's because the input and the output shouldn't be mixed... At least that's what happens on an online judge that I play around sometimes.

Comment: You initialize cases as 0, and iterate through the loop while j<cases, however, I don't see where youve changed cases

Comment: @HappyYellowFace hmm, sounds like bad design on their part. Training people to actively avoid pipeline techniques is just wrong.

Comment: Just looked at the question. They allow Java? Surely that's cheating. (BigInteger)

Comment: @Dave I completely agree with you.

Comment: @JeremyKalas `cases` is read from cin.

Comment: Also, a little tip: since it has a Time Limit, you could read a little bit about how C-standards like scanf(), fgets() and printf() are WAY much faster than cin; cout - although more dangerous aswell.

Comment: Don't return 0 if a parameter is out of range. Send a message with comprehendable content to cerr and return 1. At the end of main, return 0.

Comment: @HappyYellowFace thanks for that. Yes timing is a problem. But more so with JAVA.

Comment: If the number is in decimal form, check the 2 last digits. If it's binary, check the last 2 bits. If it's in a base that is a power of 2, check the last digit

Answer (score 10):

A number is divisible by 4 if its two last **decimal** digits are divisible by 4.

The end.

P.S. Sometimes it makes sense to stop thinking as a programmer and remember algebra/arithmetics.

Answer (score 3):

As I said in a comment, the problem is that you cannot read a 100 digit number into an int directly.  I don't want to give you the solution to the algorithm, but a hint that should help: How many digits would you need to know if the number was divisible by 2 or by 5?  And how could you extend that to 4?

Comment: Yes, the idea of the exercise is that you can determinate if a number is divisible by 4 without having to make the entire division. There is a property.

Comment: Lookup the code again. There are no n values read into an int, with each value a char is append3d to a string.

Comment: I get it now. Boy I feel dumb!

Answer (score 1):

If you express a number X as Y + d  where d = X%100 and Y = X -d we can see that Y will always be divisible by 100, for example for the number X = 343535, Y would be 343500 and d would be 35. Since Y is divisible by 100, implies that is divisible by 4, so you can determinate if X is divisible by 4, checking if d is divisible by 4, i.e the last two digits of X.

> Formally it would be:
>
> Y = 4*Z
>
> Y = 100*X +d
>
> Y = 4*Z = 4*25*X +d
>
> d = 4*(Z - 25*X)
>
> i.e if Y is multiple of 4, d is multiple of 4

You have to apply this principle to solve your problem.

Simply read a raw string and check if the number represented by the last two characters are divisible by four.

Answer (score 0):

As tempting as might be, you don't need a `BitInteger` to figure out whether a 100 digit number, of 1 million digit number is divisible by 4. That's just simple math, that you should be able to figure by yourself in a minute, if you don't know the rule.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is this `if (cases > 100)`. because of this -1 would be a valid option.
Change to `if (cases > 100 && cases < 1)` to fix it

Comment: actually, he wouldn't even need this conditional case at all: it is specified on the problem's input specification that (1<=T<=100)

Comment: That doesn't mean it going to follow the rules. it may intentionally enter a negative number to check if the specifications are met.

Comment: Online Judges don't do tricky stuff like that (at least I've never seen it), but I see your point.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't even read the whole number. I would just read the last 2 digits before the EOF char (end of file).

```
string inputString;
while(getline(cin,inputString)
{
    //code for finding x %4==0 and output
}
```

then all you need to do is convert the last 2 chars into a int and then do your mod 4 code. (you'll need a catch value for numbers < 10, but that shouldn't be hard)